# sbyte[] can be magically cast to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm not sure whether this is a .NET bug but I find it really interesting.

As expected, I cannot do this:

```
sbyte[] sbytes = { 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] bytes = sbytes; // fails: cannot convert source type 'sbyte[]' to taget type 'byte[]'
```

However, if the type of `sbytes` is `object`, this works:

```
object obj = new sbyte[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] bytes = obj as byte[];
Assert.IsNull(bytes, "WTF??")
```

**Remark 1**: The same issue occurs for `int[]` - `uint[]` and the other primitive types as well.

**Remark 2**: Though the code handles the array as a `byte[]`, the debugger loses the focus and shows `?`-s in the array.

[image: screenshot]

**Remark 3**: This works only for arrays, not for the underlying types themselves:

```
object sbyteObj = (sbyte)1;
byte byteObj = (byte)sbyteObj; // System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Ok, of course I can check the type like this:

```
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(byte[]))
```

Is this an intended behavior of the `as` operator and direct casting, or is this a .NET bug?

Comment: those question marks? i dont have this behavior. try disabling optimize code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. It's just an impedance mismatch between the C# language rules (which claim there's no conversion available) and the CLR rules (where the conversion *is* available).

Note that the compiler really, really thinks it knows best:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
// error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'sbyte[]'
sbyte[] sbytes = (sbyte[]) bytes;
```

And even when you've got code that compiles with a warning, it doesn't really do what it says:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
// warning CS0184: The given expression is never of the provided ('sbyte[]')
if (bytes is sbyte[])
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
}
```

Run that code and you *don't* get output... but if you just change the compile-time type of `bytes`, it *does* print Yes:

```
object bytes = new byte[10];
// No warning now
if (bytes is sbyte[])
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes"); // This is reached
}
```

Comment: Well, good to know that `is`, `as` and direct cast is not always trustworthy, at least not for the arrays of primitive types.

Comment: @taffer: Not sure what you mean by "not always trustworthy". If you know whether it's the compiler trying to check things, or whether it's happening at execution time, you can tell exactly what will happen.

Comment: And if I know the little tricks of the framework, I can always tell what will happen, of course. :) Btw, I have just checked, that the symptoms occur for the primitive types of the same size, except `char` and `bool`, but including `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`. I would not say that I could have predicted this behavior even after your answer.

Comment: @taffer: You can also convert between enum arrays and arrays of the enum's underlying type, btw. I think the CLI spec gives details...

Comment: Yes, but that works without arrays, too. So I can unbox an `int` from an `object` storing an enum, for example. But unboxing an `sbyte` from an `object` with a `byte` throws an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: @taffer: Yup - I believe that part of the behaviour is documented for C# as well as the CLR, although I can't remember for sure.